# mod_rewrite: Redirect to URL containing encoded values

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want a redirection to a static URL like this:

E.g. if someone navigates to `..test` on my Server he should be redirected to `http://example.tld/hello%20world`.
I tried:

```
RewriteRule test$ http://example.tld/hello%20world [L,R]
```

But that redirects to `http://example.tld/hello0world`. I tried the flags `NE` and `B` and I tried to put an actual space character in (which results in an `Internal Server Error`). I tried `hello%2520world`. I even noticed that `hello%%920world` will give me the expected result (the `%9` in the middle appearently getting ignored), but that can hardly be designed like that, can it?

How should I actually specify the redirect?

Comment: If you put in a literal space, but quote the URL `"http://example.com/hello world"` I think you'll get your desired result... Not sure though, and no time to test, hence no answer...

Answer (score 1):

OK, it took me a while to find the right part of the documentation, but now I got it:

[Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) it says:

> back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern

Thus `%20` is interpreted as a backreference `%2` (which is empty) and the literal `0`. And [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#quoting) it says:

> As of Apache 1.3.20, special characters in TestString and Substitution strings can be escaped (that is, treated as normal characters without their usual special meaning) by prefixing them with a backslash ('\') character. In other words, you can include an actual dollar-sign character in a Substitution string by using '\$'; this keeps mod_rewrite from trying to treat it as a backreference.

The chapter just talks about the `$` and actually I think that I have never seen the form %N anywhere before, but the escaping with a `\` works for the `%` as well.

Comment: For whatever reason, I found this little bit of information very difficult to find until I finally stumbled across this answer. Thank you, yankee!